# Scatter Plot in Matplotlib from Pandas DF by Multiple Categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I've got a pandas dataframe of wines - reds and whites, with all the chemical analysis data included and their respective quality ratings at the end.

I am trying to make a plot using matplotlib with "quality" as the x-axis, and "alcohol_content" along the y-axis. My data has ints for "quality" ratings. I'd like to plot the mean quality rating for each of the two types of wines ('red' or 'white', marked in the column 'type') find the mean value at each quality integer, divided by the column 'type' ('red' or 'white').

I can't seem to get it to print correctly. Running in Jupyter Notebooks.

Code Below:

```
    import matplotlib
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


    df_white = pd.read_csv('data/winequality-white.csv', delimiter = ';')
    df_red = pd.read_csv('data/winequality-red.csv', delimiter = ';')

    cols_red = df_red.columns.tolist()
    cols_red = [col.lower().replace(' ','_') for col in cols_red]
    df_red.columns = cols_red

    df_red['type'] = 'red'
    df_white['type'] = 'white'

    cols_white = df_white.columns.tolist()
    cols_white = [col.lower().replace(' ','_') for col in cols_white]
    df_white.columns = cols_white

    combined_df = df_red
    combined_df = combined_df.append(df_white)
```

Comment: Can you clarify on what you are trying to do? I can't follow this: 'I'd like to plot the mean quality rating for each of the two types of wines ('red' or 'white', marked in the column 'type') find the mean value at each quality integer, divided by the column 'type' ('red' or 'white').'

Comment: yeah! There are a lot of data points. For some alcohol contents, there are 3 or 4 or more wines that match that. It would be ideal to, instead of plotting 4 red wines at 11.2% alcohol with multiple qualities, just plot the average quality rating for red wines with 11.2% alcohol.

Comment: And all of that would be plotted along the x axis of quality and the y axis of alcohol content. (I'm hoping to eventually be able to predict the quality for a wine based on alcohol content, type (red or white) and maybe a few other factors, model dependant.

Comment: @PrestonH This is what I'm trying to plot.. if that helps.. 

`pd.pivot_table(combined_df, values='quality', index='alcohol',   columns='type', aggfunc=np.mean)`